# How to use message pack in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, serialization, deserialization, msgpack

I have to use [MessagePack](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) to deserialize data returned from a web API (ASP.net), which was Serialized using the same package.

Used the following code

```cs
public async static Task<T> DeserializeAsync<T>(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream), "Stream value cannot be null");
    }
     
    stream.Position = 0;
    T deserialized = await MessagePackSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream, MessagePack.Resolvers.ContractlessStandardResolver.Options).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return deserialized;
}
```

All was working fine in Android in debug mode but in iOS both debug and release and in Android release mode. The deserialization code crashed with the following exceptions

```
Android -> Release 

[MonoDroid]   at MessagePa07-10 18:06:01.269 I/MonoDroid(13495): MessagePack.MessagePackSerializationException: Failed to deserialize Project.Core.Models.SomeData Class value. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'FormatterCache`1' threw an exception. ---> MessagePack.Internal.MessagePackDynamicObjectResolverException: can't find public constructor. type:System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix
[MonoDroid]   at MessagePack.Internal.ObjectSerializationInfo.CreateOrNull (System.Type type, System.Boolean forceStringKey, System.Boolean contractless, System.Boolean allowPrivate) [0x009a0] in <23c4c9b023514c20801c8f07fd69206c>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at MessagePack.Internal.DynamicObjectTypeBuilder.BuildType (MessagePack.Internal.DynamicAssembly assembly, System.Type type, System.Boolean forceStringKey, System.Boolean contractless) [0x00015] in <23c4c9b023514c20801c8f07fd69206c>:0 

iOS->
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Project.Core.Helpers.BinarySerializer' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MessagePack.Resolvers.ContractlessStandardResolver' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MessagePack.Internal.StandardResolverHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MessagePack.Resolvers.DynamicEnumResolver' threw an exception. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
  at MessagePack.Internal.DynamicAssembly..ctor (System.String moduleName) [0x0001a] in <f04e2061de5c414991b8e36a20354820>:0 
  at MessagePack.Resolvers.DynamicEnumResolver..cctor () [0x00010] in <f04e2061de5c414991b8e36a20354820>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
  at MessagePack.Internal.StandardResolverHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <f04e2061de5c414991b8e36a20354820>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Found the [section](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#aot-code-generation-support-for-unityxamarin) in the MessagePack git page specifying a way to overcome this issue using an Ahead of time code generator. I followed the steps but was not able to fix the issue. Also I'm sure I'm doing it right.

How do I use MessagePack in Xamarin.Forms. Can anyone who has already suggest me or provide a reference.

**Update on steps followed**

1. Used message pack serialization in a button click.
2. Installed mpc tool.
3. Used don't mpc -i "{FormsProject.csproj path}" -o "{FormsProject directory path}"
4. Added the created message pack generated class to the forms project.
5. Used the following code in App.xaml.cs `Initialize` method

```cs
StaticCompositeResolver.Instance.Register(
     MessagePack.Resolvers.GeneratedResolver.Instance,
     MessagePack.Resolvers.StandardResolver.Instance
```

Now also the (Operation is not supported in the platform) Exception is thrown. I'm not quite getting what I'm doing wring here.

**Update 2:**

Exception in the `MessagePackSerializerOptions`

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MessagePackSerializerOptionsDefaultSettingsLazyInitializationHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MessagePack.Resolvers.StandardResolver' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MessagePack.Internal.StandardResolverHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MessagePack.Resolvers.DynamicEnumResolver' threw an exception. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
  at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly (System.Reflection.AssemblyName name, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess access) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/AssemblyBuilder.pns.cs:129 
  at MessagePack.Internal.DynamicAssembly..ctor (System.String moduleName) [0x0001a] in <f04e2061de5c414991b8e36a20354820>:0 
  at MessagePack.Resolvers.DynamicEnumResolver..cctor () [0x00010] in <f04e2061de5c414991b8e36a20354820>:0
```

Comment: You are not using the `StaticCompositeResolver` which is generated when using the `mpc` tool, you might want to look at the example code section of the "AOT Code Generation (support for Unity/Xamarin)" again

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now

Comment: @SushiHangover  Tried adding `StaticCompositeResolver ` in my project that didn't work (Operation not supported in the platform). So created a brand new solution, I have updated the question with steps I followed. I'm quite not getting it (Same not supported in platform error). I am using a mac machine. Github link https://github.com/Nikhileshwar96/GitSamples.git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to version of `MessagePack` 2.1.165 or higher.

This issue was fixed in Message pack in version 2.1.165. Regarding the lazy loading of `DynamicAssembly`.

[Issue link](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/977)

Answer (score 1):

Require to set `StaticCompositeResolver.Instance` as default.
You lacks following code.

```cs
var option = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(StaticCompositeResolver.Instance);
MessagePackSerializer.DefaultOptions = option;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying back. But an error is thrown even at `MessagePackSerializerOptions ` usage. I have added the exception to the query.

Comment: An issue was resolved in message pack nuget pack regarding lazy loading of default resolver. Works fine after 2.1.165 version. [Git issue link](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/977) Thanks @neuecc.